# HTML 5 Video tag not working in Firefox

Tags: html, html5-video

I am working in asp.net mvc and using `<video src="Video_File.mp4" controls><video>` tag to show a video. This works well in Chrome but not in Firefox. What is problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is that Firefox does not currently support MP4 format.  See [supported media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) for a list of what is and isn't supported.

Generally two file formats are required; WebM and MP4 to cover support across the latest browsers.

Comment: FLV format video also not works. Error message: "Plugin missing", but when i clicked search automatically for missing plugin, i got error message telling that no required plugin found.

Comment: flv is flash video. No browsers have native support for flash video's.  You must use a flash video plug-in for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats), MP4 is currently not a supported format in Firefox.